DIV 'contain' like an image to keep scaled proportions
I have an image which has a css property of object-fit: contain which scales the proportions of the image correctly as I change the canvas dimensions. I am trying to build a grid on top of it where a person can select different areas of the image, like so:

I have used everything from static DIV's to flex boxes and now Im settling down into a CSS Grid. With a uniform aspect ratio this works correctly, however as soon as I scale to something non-uniform the image correctly updates however the boxes don't scale as well, as seen below:

I can set the image to not fit which then 'fixes' the issue, but then Im left with a very badly proportioned character.


This is a personal project so Im happy to show any source code as needed. So far I have this:
        <v-img src="../assets/images/character.png"
               max-height="calc(100vh - 80px)">
               
            <div class="selectGrid">

                <div class="item head justify-center">
                    <div></div>
                </div>

                <div class="item chest justify-center">
                    <div></div>
                </div>

                <div class="item bottom justify-center">
                    <div></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </v-img>

<style scoped>
.selectGrid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr minmax(30px, 150px) 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 15% 4% 20% 5% 42%;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". . head . ."
        ". . . . ."
        ". chest chest chest ."
        ". . . . ."
        "bottom bottom bottom bottom bottom"
        ". . . . .";
}

.item {
    display: flex;
}

.item>div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.head {
    grid-area: head;
}

.chest {
    grid-area: chest;
}

.bottom {
    grid-area: bottom;
}

.r-hand {
    grid-area: rhand;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    .item.head>div {
        max-width: 50px;
    }

    .item.chest>div {
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 165px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width:960px) {
    .item.head>div {
        max-width: 100px;
    }

    .item.chest>div {
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 250px;
    }
}


@media (min-width:960px) {
    .item.head>div {
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .item.chest>div {
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .bottom>div {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: calc(400px -(100vh / 10));
    }
}
</style>

Edit; if anyone wants to give this a go here is the character:


One cup of coffee later and I have an answer. Hope it helps someone with this kind of niche use-case in the future.
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="scaled-child">
        <div class="scale-child-holder">
            <!-- SCALED CONTENT GOES HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.parent-container {
    /* Styles for the parent container, if needed */
    width: 100%;
    /* Ensures it fills the available space */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.scaled-child {
    /* Required for padding calculation */
    position: relative;

    /* Initial size based on aspect ratio */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* Max width of the image */
    max-width: 468px;
    /* Max height of the image */
    max-height: 1000px;

    /* This is the key to maintaining aspect ratio. It's calculated by dividing the original height (1000) by the original width (478) and multiplying by 100% to get a percentage value. */
    padding-top: 106.25%;

    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    /* Ensure padding doesn't affect width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Optional to hide content overflow if needed */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scaled-child:after {
    content: "";
    /* Ensures content fills the entire div */
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.scale-child-holder {
    /* Now your content has freedom */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

